# Как написать сложный SQL запрос

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть такая база данных. Таблица заказы (Orders) и продукты (Products) связанны через связующую таблицу OrderProducts.
[image: Схема БД]
Делаю такой вот запрос

```
SELECT 
    Orders.id as NЗаказа,
    Products.name as НаименованиеПродукта,
    Products.price as Цена,
    OrderProducts.quantity as Количество,
    Products.price * OrderProducts.quantity as Стоимость
FROM 
    Orders,
    OrderProducts,
    Products
WHERE
    OrderProducts.order_id = Orders.id AND
    OrderProducts.product_id = Products.id
```

На выходе
[image: выходная таблица] 
Как мне написать такой запрос что бы выводилась стоимость заказа при том что в заказе может быть несколько позиций?

Comment: Вы бы добавили метку используемой вами базы данных(mysql, mssql ну и т.п.)

Comment: Это не с sql-ex задача? Знакомо выглядит )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

думаю как то так ( если нужна только номер заказа и стоимость)

```
SELECT 
    Orders.id as NЗаказа,
    sum( Products.price * OrderProducts.quantity ) as Стоимость
FROM 
    Orders,
    OrderProducts,
    Products
WHERE
    OrderProducts.order_id = Orders.id AND
    OrderProducts.product_id = Products.id

group by Orders.id
```

плюс на мой взгляд через left join выглядело бы понятнее

```
SELECT 
        Orders.id as NЗаказа,
        sum( Products.price * OrderProducts.quantity ) as Стоимость
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN  OrderProducts on OrderProducts.order_id = Orders.id 
LEFT JOIN Products on OrderProducts.product_id = Products.id
group by Orders.id
```